# JWT-Auth: Algorithm not supported for SSL

Tags: laravel

I followed [this link](https://medium.com/@mosesesan/tutorial-5-how-to-build-a-laravel-5-4-jwt-authentication-api-with-e-mail-verification-61d3f356f823) to use JWT-Auth in my Laravel project until step 4 and replaced the authentication logic in Step 5 with my own validation and a call of

```
$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
```

When I try to call this login I receive an exception:

```
Could not create token: The algorithm 'HS256' is not supported for OpenSSL
```

This occurs with any of the algorithms mentioned [here](https://github.com/namshi/jose/tree/2.2.0/src/Namshi/JOSE/Signer).

Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by doing a composer-remove on the jwt-auth package and adding it again.